# Does the proof of membership of other leaf nodes have to be updated if a new node is added to a Merkle Patricia Trie?

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, proof

If a new leaf node is added to a Merkle Patricia Trie, should proofs for other nodes be updated?
In other words, if I have a proof for node A in a Merkle Patricia Trie and node B gets added to it, do I need to update my proof?